# What's the best way to catch wild Pokémon in Pokémon GO?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics

In the newly released Pokémon GO, one of the major activities of the game is to catch wild Pokémon. These Pokémon are shown in the "nearby" list and their "rough distance" (RD) to you can be 0, 1, 2, or 3 footprints. If they are further than 3 footprints away, they disappear from the nearby list. So a Pokémon cannot appear with 4 or more footprints.

[image: From https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/t_original/klzm3pqglj8iqd5aik0t.png]

Although Niantic Labs has not released a concrete definition of what the footprints mean, I'll define them as follows. An RD of $x \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ means the Pokémon in question is in the circular band enclosed by two circles of radius $x$ and $x-1$, closed on the outer circumference and open on the inner circumference. E.g., if the number of footprints is 3, then the Pokémon's actual distance from you (at the origin of the Cartesian plane) is in $[3,2[$.

[image: Showing possible position of a Pokémon with RD 3]

What is the best way to triangulate the position of a Pokémon?

---

One of the ambiguities of this question is the fact that "footprints" is undefined in terms of metres. It is said that one footprint is roughly 100 metres, but I can't confirm it. So, it is not true to say that walking 300 metres in any direction will affect the footprints, as 3 footprints may be much larger than 300 metres.

Given a Pokémon at an unknown point $(x,y)$ with RD $r$ footprints, pick a random direction and observe if the RD decreases or stays the same. If it does not and instead increases, stop (call this point $A$). Go in the opposite direction (do an about-face) and continue walking.

Stop when the $RD$ increases again. Call this point $B$. Go to the midpoint of $A$ and $B$. Choose a direction perpendicular to your original line. Continue in that direction until you reach the Pokémon (RD becomes zero), or, if it increases, turn around and head in the opposite direction, continuing past the midpoint of $A$ and $B$.

---

Discussion:

Will this method always find the Pokémon? I believe it will, because we have symmetry in the RD. I.e., if the Pokémon is 3 footprints from you, you are 3 footprints from it. So we can view your path as a line intersecting the circular bands of the Pokémon's $RD$. Since the line segment between $A$ and $B$ defines a chord on the Pokémon's $RD$ (circular bands), a line perpendicular to $AB$ intersecting the midpoint of $A$ and $B$ will pass through the centre of the circle (the Pokémon's position).

In the worst case, you would walk in all four directions. In the best case, you would've picked the direction the Pokémon is in and found them without backtracking.

Is there a better way to do this? I imagine something involving spirals may be better, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by best way? They have different merits

Comment: Least distance walked. :) But please don't tell me to walk in some discontinuous fractal-like function as this is physically impossible (not usually a concern of mathematicians, I know). ;)

Comment: @TROLLKILLER actually, maybe it would be nice to see how this problem can be optimised in different ways but as far as I'm concerned the only thing to optimise would be distance walked. Perhaps this could be done by some "smart" choice of initial angle to walk at, but I'll leave it up to other responders.

Comment: I thought perhaps the question had many upvotes due to the raging popularity of the game, possibly with the help of the Hot Network Questions list. But it's a nice question on its own, nicely done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a picture that should help. Basically, you walk around until you find a boundary where the number of foot prints changes. The most efficient way to do that is to walk in one direction. When you reach the boundary, mark your point, then walk in a tight circle around the point. Pay attentention to the number of paw prints. There will be two points where the number of paw prints changes, mark them. You now have three points equidistant from your Pokémon.

Triangulate and Go Catch Em All!

[image]

Comment: PSA: please don't triangulate while driving.

Comment: @AlexR. Also, don't Pokémon Go and drive.

Comment: One might add that, if the three points are almost in a line, then you just walk perpendicular to that line in the appropriate direction (which you know by noting whether the distance increases/decreases) - this will be a more stable computation than actually computing the center. (And, in practical terms, the GPS resolution puts certain limits on how small your circle can be)

Comment: @Milo Brandt Yes I was going to comment about the GPS's resolution as well. However, I think the minimum radius for your circle can be determined by seeing how far one has to walk (or backtrack) to see the RD change (increasing or decreasing will be enough). We could also attempt a spiral of some sort but I'm not sure what the spiral's length would be like compared to a small set of concentric circles.